# Qt5 visual studio addin 2010 - "Choose Resource"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt5, add-in

I've tried to set icon of a button by means qt designer add-in for visual studio 2010.

When i select "Choose resource" in qt visual studio addin, my qt designer freeze.

Help me for this issue. Thanks

Comment: Do you have `WindowPager` application installed on your computer?

Comment: No, i have not installed WindowPager.

Comment: You can press `Esc` to unfreeze qt designer. I have the same problem but didn't find time to investigate it...

Comment: Thanks, it works, but the resource chooser dialog not show. I'll add icons manually

Comment: It also happens from time to time for me...I haven't been able to reproduce it